# Flag column creation in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a really frustrating silly example. Let's say I have the following data below with an ID column...

```
dat <- data.frame(cbind(rep(c("a","b","c"),c(1,3,1))))
names(dat) <- c("ID")
dat

   ID
1  a
2  b
3  b
4  b
5  c
6  c
```

I am trying to create a new column using the dplyr package which creates a 0 for the first row by ID and then any subsequent rows will have a 1. So the resulting data should look like this:

```
   ID Flag
1  a  0
2  b  0
3  b  1
4  b  1
5  c  0
6  c  1
```

I have tried the following code but just get a column of zeros:

```
dat %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
mutate(
 Readmission = ifelse(n() == 1,0,c(0,rep(1,n()-1)))
) %>% data.frame()
```

Any help appreciated! Surely this is a quick fix and I didn't sleep enough last night. This is actually a pretty simple task using lapply... but it takes too bloody long to run and I'm impatient.

Comment: Try this:  `ifelse(dat$ID==dplyr::lag(dat$ID), 1, 0)`

Comment: No getting some NAs.

Comment: If you remove the `group_by` function, then only the first row should generate "NA"

Comment: try `ifelse(row_number()==1,1,0)`

Comment: had to flip if/else results, but that works... cheers m8!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n()` is the number of rows, but you need the actual row number. Here the solution:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    Readmission = ifelse(row_number()==1, 0, 1)
  ) %>% 
  data.frame()
```